# Nested SCSS styles not working in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, webpack, webpacker

I'm using Rails with webpacker.  Everything works fine locally but as soon as I push up to heroku it breaks.

I removed everything except my own scss and noticed some styles weren't loading in production.

For example in the same file, `.fabric-container` will not be present, but `#renderCanvas` will:

```
.fabric-container {
    display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 10%;
  overflow: hidden;


  &:after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    margin-top: 100%;
  }
}

#renderCanvas {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  opacity: .6;
}
```

Here is a shot of the css with everything else stripped out, and on the bottom is the css of the page on prod.  Totally missing `.canvas-container`  Works fine locally!

[image: Code on top, output in production on bottom]

Comment: You mention the style s being nested, those do not look nested, are they nested or not?

Comment: The pseudo element &:after is nested in .fabric-container so I find it odd that thats the one thats not coming through in production.

Comment: oh, but the other `.fabric-container` styles are applied?

Answer (score 0):

Many red herrings in this debug session... but I knew SOMETHING was altering the output css.

Turns out Rails Jumpstart Pro includes tailwind and purgecss.

> We have included PurgeCSS by default to automatically remove unused
> CSS when deploying to production. This greatly reduces the size of
> TailwindCSS in production to deliver a much faster experience in
> production.

This is located in `postcss.config.js` which is why I didn't see it in `config/environments` etc.

So if this is happening to you, check `postcss.config.js`, and either add your files there or remove it altogether!